# Measurability of uncountable union of measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E \subset (0,1) \times (0,1)$ be a set such that $E \cap (\{p\}\times (0,1))$ is (Lebesgue)-measurable and such that $E \cap (\{p\}\times (0,1))$ has full one-dimensional Lebesgue measure for every $p \in (0,1)$  . Is the set $E$ then also (Lebesgue)-measurable?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement that any set $E\cap(\{p\}\times(0,1))$ needs to have measure $1$, makes things a bit more difficult, but the Answer is still no.

Define

$$
E\cap(\{p\}\times(0,1)) := 
\{p\}\times[(0,1)\setminus (\mathbb{Q}+\epsilon(p))]
$$

where $\epsilon: (0,1)\to \{0,\pi\}$ is non-measurable, i.e. $\epsilon^{-1}(0)$ is not measurable.

Therefore the slice

$$
E\cap ((0,1)\times\{1/2\}) = \epsilon^{-1}(\pi)\times\{1/2\}
$$
is not measurable.